# rownum & aliasing in HQL

Tags: select, hql, alias, rownum

Need help...

how to translate this SQL query to HQL :

```
select "row" from (select rownum as "row", globalId from globalTable where valid='T') where globalId = "g123";

globalTable  :  
globalId _ valid  
g000 _ T  
g111 _ F  
g222 _ T  
g123 _ T
```

it should return 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your query can be converted one query:

```
select rownum as "row" from globalTable where valid='T' and globalId = "g123"
```